# Cypher result order in Neo4j movie database is not displaying in proper way

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to find random 100 movies and then sort the result using movie id. and for this, I am using below query:

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)
WHERE RAND() < 0.3
RETURN movie.title as title,movie.id AS id
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 100
```

But the result is not ok:

title-----------------------------------------id

Major League---------------------------9942

El Chupacabra-------------------------9937

Hallettsville------------------------------9935

Sleuth-------------------------------------993

The Ringer-------------------------------9927

BloodRayne-----------------------------9926

---

`993` should be on the bottom of the list but it's in the wrong position. can anyone suggest me how can I solve it?

Comment: Your displayed results are in *ascending* (not descending) alphanumeric order. Are you sure that you specified `DESC`?

Comment: added the output again. check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id property values on your nodes are strings, not integers. The string "102" comes before any string prefixed with "102", which would explain your ordering.

When setting id properties on your nodes, leave off quotation marks to work with integers instead of strings.

Where did you get the movie database from, and what version of Neo4j are you using? On Neo4j 3.1 there are no id properties in the movie graph.

EDIT

After downloading the example database from your link, I can confirm it's using string id values. Because of this, any comparisons and ordering on this property will be string based, not numerical.

In a real graph, you would want to make sure you're using the correct data type for your properties from the beginning.

For the sake of this query, if you didn't want to transform all of the id properties to integers, then you can at least transform the values you're working with in the query and sort based on those (it won't save them back to the graph, so the properties will remain string based though the sort in your query will be correct).

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)
WHERE RAND() < 0.3
RETURN movie.title as title,movie.id AS id
ORDER BY toInt(id) DESC
LIMIT 100
```

EDIT 2

The reason why you're only getting higher values is because your query explicitly orders the results first, then takes the top 100 of the ordered results. If you want to avoid this, take 100 results first, and THEN order them:

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)
WHERE RAND() < 0.3
WITH movie LIMIT 100
RETURN movie.title as title,movie.id AS id
ORDER BY toInt(id) DESC
```

If you want more variation in the ids of the movies picked, then you'll want to alter the threshold on the random number. Right now 30% of the movie nodes are in the result set before the limit. You may want to choose a lower value.

Comment: thanks, I got it. I have downloaded the database from here:  https://neo4j.com/developer/example-data/#_the_data_sets

How can I solve this problem in this database? 
I am using neo4j 3.1.0

Comment: thank you. I have checked using this. But in this case, values are coming only from higher values and values are too close with one each other though the list contains 50, thousands of movies.

Comment: Added some explanation and suggestions to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton. you have helped me a lot to understand this concept :)